# DELETE android com Webservice URL não funciona

Tags: php, android, web-service, delete

Estou com um problema chato que ainda não consegui resolver e envolve PHP e Android (mais PHP na verdade).

Estou acessando um WebService em PHP que faz uma operação de acordo com cada método requisitado pelo Android (por exemplo: `POST` faz insert, `PUT` faz update, etc.), todos os métodos `POST, PUT e GET` estão funcionando tranquilo, mas o `DELETE` não.

Vou mostrar o trecho do código em PHP e tentar explicar:

```
else if ($metodoHttp == 'DELETE') {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM hotel_db.Hotel WHERE id=?");
    $segments = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $id = $segments[count($segments)-1];
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $jsonRetorno = array("id"=>$id);
    echo json_encode($jsonRetorno);
}
```

Nesse código, a página em PHP verifica se o método é o `DELETE` e se for, pega o parâmetro que vem junto com a URL depois da `/` deleta o registro no banco de dados com esse id, e retorna o id do registro excluído.

No android pedi para escrever no Log a URL que estava sendo enviada para ver se estava indo certo e ela esta indo assim:

http://meusite.com/bruno/Exemplos/Post/webservice.php/11

Não sei se há algum erro no código em PHP(no modo como recupera o id na URL) pois no android parece estar tudo certo.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema era no webservice php na linha:<p><code>$segments = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);</code><p> O metodo <code>$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]</code> não funciona no meu servidor então troquei para <code>$_SERVER["ORIG_PATH_INFO"]</code> e funcionou.